# Android Studio in Mac, Cannot Paste Images to Res/Drawable

Tags: android, macos, android-resources

I'm using Mac and willing to copy some images/icon to my android studio project. But everytime i did copy-paste, it always failed to copy file to Res/Drawable also using Drag method.

My Android Studio is 1.5.0 and My OSX is 10.10.5
I've tried to restart my macbook but still face this...

Any Solution ?

Comment: when it "failed to copy" is there an error message of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have osx 10.11.1 and Android Studio 1.5. It happened sometimes and I dont know why. Maybe when reindexing project or something like that.

You can easily use Reveal in Finder menu over drawable folder and add any file in Finder. U will see the file in drawable in Android Studio.

Comment: Hi, it help, many thanks. However, Do i need to create drawable-hdpi or etc ? Because if i drop all images file in drawable, android studio seems not automatically split into drawable-size folder...

Comment: oh no, beside i cannot copy paste. Also, i can't create folder under res on android studio...what happen to my mac ?

Comment: Yea exactly make folder this name

Comment: U can make it in finder

Answer (score 0):

using osx 10.10.5 with Android Studio 1.5.0 works fine for me. Maybe there is an permission issue if projekt isn't located in home folder.

Comment: i'm using Android Studio 1.5, also OSX 10.10.5, project folder path is default. but still cannot copy paste...